# If gluons can make other gluons, why don't they keep multiplying into infinity?

Tags: particle-physics, gluons

[This video from Physics Videos by Eugene Khutoryansky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoR3hq5b5yE) says that since gluons have color charge, they can attract each other by making more gluons, and this is why the strong force doesn't behave like the electromagnetic force. But shouldn't those gluons be able to make gluons of their own? Why doesn't this happen recursively and explode off into infinity? Can virtual particles only be produced at a finite rate?

Comment: "can virtual particles only be produced at a finite rate?" Virtual particles are mathematical artifacts of quantum field theory, not actual particles. The strong force is better understood non-perturbatively for the confinement, where the concept of particles is not really a thing.

Comment: What does that last sentence mean?

Comment: It means that since particles are perturbations/excitations of a field, they are not the right tool to use to understand non-perturbative effects. Since the form of the QCD potential differs from the shape of the QED one at a non-perturbative regime, it is essentially a non-perturbative effect that explains it.

Comment: So virtual particles aren't really distinct or countable things>

Comment: virtual particles are just not well-defined in a nonperturbative setting

Comment: What does nonperturbative mean

Comment: Gluons split to gluons, but the reverse happens with virtually equal probability.